# Get list of id's in an arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, lambda

i have a list of checked user where i need to convert this list to a list of id's and then create a `concatenated string` but i am stuck in my lambda expression

```
 String [] arr = CheckedUsers.stream(users).filter(u-> u.getID()+"" ).toArray(); // this give error

  String str=  TextUtils.join(",", arr);
```

Can anyone help me ?

[image]

Comment: Sora, can you tell us what is the problem? Looking to your code I think that it is alright.

Comment: i've updated my question

Comment: Besides the red underline, if you try to run it what is the stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use lambdas but you are compiling with Java 7.

The support for lambdas was added only in java 8.

You have two options:

- Change your app to compile with java 8: https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html
- Use retrolambda do add support for lambda function with java 7: https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

Comment: i've done this and fix the compiling issue though i am having two error one on `stream(users)` that say : Expression expected, and one on `u.getID()+""` that say : string cannot be converted to boolean

Comment: You are using filter, the filter method expect the return of a boolean, so only the objects that filter returned true are returned. What you need is the map method instead of filter.

Answer (score 0):

The `stream` method should be called without parameters on the list itself. Also filter is not what you need in this case as it would only filter out values from the list.

One way of achieving what you need:

1. Transform the user' ids into strings. `map` would be required in this case.
2. Concatenate values in the stream. We want 1 value out of all the values in the stream. `reduce` operations do this.

Java code implementing this:

`String concatenatedIds = users.stream().map(u -> Integer.toString(u.getId())).reduce("", String::concat));`

Here is a working example: http://ideone.com/hkYzjv.
Hope this helps.